# Android Studio - emulator: how to test API 15 x86 Google API

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play

I want to test my app on older emulated devices but I cannot.

e.g. API 15, I've installed the following packages:

[image]

but when I'm prompted to chose the AVD's image, I cannot find it:

[image]

The first one doesn't load, hangs for ever and it would be anyway useless as without Google APIs.

The second is arm and

[image]

but doesn't work anyway (yes, I've installed the armeabi-v7a system image).

What am I missing ?

Comment: I have the kind of the same problem, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @Eduardo: no, not found sorry.